# Retrieving profiles from a table based on specific logic

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to extract profiles from a table for the below criteria:

1. There are 5 IDs in total. 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500
2. The profiles to have atleast one ID of each value 100, 300 and 400. IDs with value 200 and 500 should not be present even once.
3. Profile can have multiple number of IDs of value 300 and 400 but will have only one ID of value 100.
4. The profiles will have IDs 300 and 400 equally. i.e For every ID will the value 300, there will be an ID of value 400.

**Eg**:

*TABLE A*:

```
-------------------------
PROFILE_ID          ID
-------------------------
12345               100
12345               300
12345               400
23456               100
23456               300
23456               400
23456               300
23456               400
34567               100
34567               200
-------------------------
```

The result should fetch PROFILE_IDs 12345 and 23456 and not 34567.

I am pretty stuck and blank in getting a clear idea on how to frame a query for this. Please help.

Comment: Why 12345, as rule #2 says that there must not be ID = 200 nor 500 (12345 has one row with ID = 200)?

Comment: Oh yes @Littlefoot. My bad. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * From test;

PROFILE_ID         ID
---------- ----------
     12345        100
     12345        300
     12345        400
     23456        100
     23456        300
     23456        400
     23456        300
     23456        400
     34567        100
     34567        200

10 rows selected.
```

one option is to do it rule-by-rule, each of CTEs retrieving data which satisfy certain rule. The final result is intersection of these `PROFILE_ID`s.

```
SQL> with
  2  rule2 as  -- don't allow IDs 200 nor 500
  3    (select profile_id
  4     from test
  5     where profile_id not in (select profile_id
  6                              from test
  7                              where id in (200, 500)
  8                             )
  9    ),
 10  rule3 as  -- there can be only one ID = 100 for each PROFILE_ID
 11    (select profile_id
 12     from (select profile_id,
 13             sum(case when id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_100
 14           from test
 15           group by profile_id
 16          )
 17     where cnt_100 = 1
 18    ),
 19  rule4 as  -- number of IDs 300 and 400 has to be equal and greater than 0
 20    (select profile_id
 21     from (select profile_id,
 22             sum(case when id = 300 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_300,
 23             sum(case when id = 400 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_400
 24           from test
 25           group by profile_id
 26          )
 27     where cnt_300  = cnt_400
 28       and cnt_300 > 0
 29    )
 30  select profile_id from rule2
 31  intersect
 32  select profile_id from rule3
 33  intersect
 34  select profile_id from rule4;

PROFILE_ID
----------
     12345
     23456

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, since all your rules rely on counting the different `id`s, I'd do it more like this. Some of this is redundant, but it makes explicit which part comes from which of your criteria.

```
with rules as (
  select profile_id,
         sum(case when id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_100,
         sum(case when id = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_200,
         sum(case when id = 300 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_300,
         sum(case when id = 400 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_400,
         sum(case when id = 500 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_500
    from table1
   group by profile_id
)
select profile_id
  from rules
       -- rule 1
 where cnt_100 > 0
   and cnt_300 > 0
   and cnt_400 > 0
       -- rule 2
   and cnt_200 = 0
   and cnt_500 = 0
       -- rule 3
   and cnt_100 = 1
       -- rule 4
   and cnt_300 = cnt_400
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926a42/3)